# Personal Sites site collections only being created on default.aspx

Tags: 2013, site-collection, my-site

I am having problems with the self service creation when the system account's site collection is being created automatically in a customized My Site Host.

If I go to  `http://mypersonalsite/default.aspx` the site collection creates itself automatically but if I go to `http://mypersonalsite/person.aspx` not the same happens. It is not being created.

Is there any proccess that occurs in default.aspx that doesn't in person.aspx?

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my issue with the following code in a Feature in the activate method.

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
try
{
    using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("person.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {

        ......
        ......

        manager.AddWebPart(new MySiteFirstRunExperienceWebPart() { IsVisible = false }, "Central", 1);
        manager.AddWebPart(new MySitePersonalSiteUpgradeOnNavigationWebPart() { IsVisible = false }, "Central", 2); 
        ......
        ......
    }
}
```

And adding this to person.aspx

```
<SPSWC:StringValueEx ResourceFile="spscore" LocId="MySiteHost_PageTitle" runat="server"/>
```

I hope it helps everyone.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly there are one or two hidden webparts on default.aspx that initiate the process, and also bring up the modal "let's get social"

Comment: I have already tried with this approach but with no success.
In fact I have replicate default.aspx into person.aspx and still not working.